# Image not Show after upload to VPS

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, hosting, centos7, vps

[Upload Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8UCZT.png)

[here after upload success](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kaow6.png)

Im use Vps (google cloud)
Os : Centos7

if im use the hosting all work normally

Thanks for help...

Comment: check from `view page source`. How does it call the image

Comment: the image 404 not found